# How to fill a polygon with a custom hatch in matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, polygons, hatchstyle

I'm using python and matplotlib to create several closed polygons. I then need to fill them with a hatch, which can be done through set_hatch.

http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html

Unfortunately I am working with greyscale images, and I need more hatches than provided by default - I would prefer to provide a bitmap (or some similar image) which could be tiled instead of using these hatches with varying densities.

I am open to other python libraries (pyglet, pygame, PIL, etc) however I would prefer the solution to be in python.

Comment: There's an example of [custom hatches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745937/how-to-decrease-hatch-density-in-matplotlib?rq=1) here, but the author says it's brittle.

Comment: The standard set_hatch has eight distinct hatches, each of which can operate in at least two densities, and which can be combined. I would think a plot would be too confusing long before you ran out of combinations of hatches. Do you have an example of greyscale hatching with dozens of usable fills?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subclass `matplotlib.hatch.Shapes` and define a custom hatch based on any reference path drawn inside unit square [[-0.5, 0.5] x [-0.5, 0.5]].

Tentative:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.hatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Polygon


house_path = Polygon(
    [[-0.3, -0.4], [0.3, -0.4], [0.3, 0.1], [0., 0.4], [-0.3, 0.1]],
    closed=True, fill=False).get_path()

class CustomHatch(matplotlib.hatch.Shapes):
    """
    Custom hatches defined by a path drawn inside [-0.5, 0.5] square.
    Identifier 'c'.
    """
    filled = True
    size = 1.0
    path = house_path

    def __init__(self, hatch, density):
        self.num_rows = (hatch.count('c')) * density
        self.shape_vertices = self.path.vertices
        self.shape_codes = self.path.codes
        matplotlib.hatch.Shapes.__init__(self, hatch, density)

matplotlib.hatch._hatch_types.append(CustomHatch)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ellipse = ax.add_patch(Ellipse((0.5, 0.5), 0.3, 0.5, fill=False))
ellipse.set_hatch('c')
ellipse.set_color('red')
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]