# Fill polygon with custom hatch with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, polygon

I want to fill a bunch of polygons with line hatch. The lines must have a specific angle with respect to x-axis. I found that matplotlib already suppots some hatch classes and one can define a custom class (like [How to fill a polygon with a custom hatch in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285154/how-to-fill-a-polygon-with-a-custom-hatch-in-matplotlib)). I tried to generate a custom hatch but when I append it to the list of hatches the init function doesn't know the angle. I tried with the following class:

```
class AngularHatch(HatchPatternBase):
    def __init__(self, hatch, density, angle):
        self.num_lines = int((hatch.count('{'))*density*3)
        self.num_vertices = self.num_lines * 2
        self.R = np.array([[np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
                       [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])

    def set_vertices_and_codes(self, vertices, codes):
        steps, stepsize = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, self.num_lines, False,
                                  retstep=True)
        steps += stepsize / 2.
        vertices[0::2, 0] = 0
        vertices[0::2, 1] = steps
        vertices[1::2, 0] = 1
        vertices[1::2, 1] = steps
        for i, v in enumerate(vertices):
            vertices[i] = self.R.dot(v)
    codes[0::2] = Path.MOVETO
    codes[1::2] = Path.LINETO
```

Then I add this class to the list of available classes for hatching. However this will not generate the correct lines since the code is modified from the HorizontalHatch source code [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/38be7aeaaac3691560aeadafe46722dda427ef47/lib/matplotlib/hatch.py) and I think this generates lines in the unit square. Moreover I need to generate this patch for a specific angle for each polygon I want to render. ¿Any ideas on how to give the correct angle to this class per polygon?

Answer (score 3):

**The following does not solve this issue. It just solves part of the problem and shows at which point the approach fails. I am currently convinced that hatching with arbitrary angles is not possible with matplotlib, because the size of the unit cell is fixed.**

To overcome the problem of setting the angle, one may define a custom format from which to take the angle information. E.g. `"{angle}{factor}"`, such that `"{45}{2}"` would produce a hatching with an angle of 45° and a density factor of 2.

I then do not completely understand the attempt of calculating the vertices. To replicate the behaviour of the hatches which are built-in, one may rotate them directly.

The problem is that this way the line hatches work only for angles of 45°. This is because the lines at the edges of the unit cell do not align well. See the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.hatch
import matplotlib.path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Rectangle

class AngularHatch(matplotlib.hatch.HatchPatternBase):
    def __init__(self, hatch, density):
        self.num_lines=0
        self.num_vertices=0
        if hatch[0] == "{":
            h = hatch.strip("{}").split("}{")
            angle = np.deg2rad(float(h[0])-45)
            d = float(h[1])
            self.num_lines = int(density*d)
            self.num_vertices = (self.num_lines + 1) * 2
            self.R = np.array([[np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
                                [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])

    def set_vertices_and_codes(self, vertices, codes):

        steps = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, self.num_lines + 1, True)

        vertices[0::2, 0] = 0.0 + steps
        vertices[0::2, 1] = 0.0 - steps
        vertices[1::2, 0] = 1.0 + steps
        vertices[1::2, 1] = 1.0 - steps
        codes[0::2] = matplotlib.path.Path.MOVETO
        codes[1::2] = matplotlib.path.Path.LINETO
        vertices[:,:] = np.dot((vertices-0.5),self.R)+0.5



matplotlib.hatch._hatch_types.append(AngularHatch)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ellipse = ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.4, 0.8, fill=False))
ellipse.set_hatch('{45}{1}')
ellipse.set_color('red')
ellipse = ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.55, 0.1), 0.4, 0.8, fill=False))
ellipse.set_hatch('{22}{1}')
ellipse.set_color('blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I will redact an answer soon, I gave a +1 because it was a helpful answer, but I could not do it using matplotlib alone, I ended using Shapely with their multilinestring class. Actually I think the question and its answer comes from another stackexchange website.